# testing admin.ModelAdmin in django

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-admin

I am trying to find out the best way for testing `admin.ModelAdmin` in `admin.py`. Specifically I am overriding the `save_model()` function which I want to test. From the research I have done, the only solution I have found was writing a request/response test and then query the database.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Check out Django's [`ModelAdminTests`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/modeladmin/tests.py) for examples.

Answer (score 83):

As suggested in [Udi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6498681), we can study Django's own [ModelAdmin tests](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/modeladmin/tests.py), to determine the basic ingredients for a `ModelAdmin` test. Here's a summary:

### Basic ingredients

In addition to the Django `TestCase` stuff, the basic ingredients are:

1. An instance of `AdminSite`:

   ```
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite
   ```
2. Your model class and corresponding `ModelAdmin` (sub)class:

   ```
    from my_app.models import MyModel
    from my_app.admin import MyModelAdmin
   ```
3. Optionally, depending on your needs, a (mock) request and/or form.

### Recipe

The first two ingredients are required to create an instance of your (custom) `ModelAdmin`:

```
my_model_admin = MyModelAdmin(model=MyModel, admin_site=AdminSite())
```

Based on the [ModelAdmin source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/#ModelAdmin.save_model), the default `save_model` implementation only requires an instance of your model, so it can be called, for example, as follows:

```
my_model_admin.save_model(obj=MyModel(), request=None, form=None, change=None)
# some test assertions here
```

It all depends on what your `save_model` does, and what you want to test.
Suppose your `save_model` checks user permissions, then you would need to provide a `request` (i.e. the third ingredient) with a valid user, in addition to the model instance:

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock

...

my_user = User.objects.create(...)
my_model_admin.save_model(
    obj=MyModel(), request=Mock(user=my_user), form=None, change=None
)
# some test assertions here
```

Here we use [`unittest.mock.Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class) to create a mock-request. Based on the Django test [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/420f3230a229ee5602025724774a768838b94fac/tests/modeladmin/tests.py#L38), a minimal `request` consists of a Python `object` with a `user` attribute.
The `user` attribute may refer to a mock user, or an [actual instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62579906) of your `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, depending on your needs. An alternative would be to use  [django.test.RequestFactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory).

This basic approach applies to the other `ModelAdmin` methods as well.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I got lots of great clues and boilerplate code from this.

Answer (score 6):

You can specify custom modelform for modeladmin then simply test this modelform ;)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form

**forms**

```
class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
```

**admin**

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SomeModelForm


admin.site.register(SomeModel, SomeModelAdmin)
```

**tests**

```
class TestSomeModel(TestCase):
    def test_form(self):
        form = SomeModelForm(**kwargs)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
        # ...
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this doesn't reliably tests **saving** the object.

Answer (score 0):

To test if the search does not lead to server errors (i.e. because `search_fields` are not correct) you can use the following code:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse


class TestModelAdmins(TestCase):
    def test_search_fields(self):
        user_1 = User(
            username="user1",
            first_name="User",
            last_name="One",
            email="user1@example.org",
            password="superSecurePasswordFromStackoverflow",
            is_superuser=True,
            is_staff=True,
        )
        user_1.full_clean()
        user_1.save()
        self.client.force_login(user_1)
        for model_class, admin_class in admin.site._registry.items():
            with self.subTest(model_class._meta.model_name):
                path = reverse("admin:%s_%s_changelist" % (model_class._meta.app_label, model_class._meta.model_name))
                response = self.client.get(path + "?q=blub")
                self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```