# Django create new user without password

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm creating new users using a custom `UserCreationForm` and then using `password_reset` from `auth.views` with a customized email template to send a signup mail to the user.

This process is working fine, users are able to successfully complete the signup process and start using the app. I now want to create users without having to set a password for the user.

I tried setting `self.fields['password1'].required` and `self.fields['password2'].required` to `False`
in the `UserCreationForm` init method as recommended [here](http://django-authtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/how-to/invitation-email.html) but that hasn't worked for me. Unfortunately, it's proving difficult to debug. I'm not seeing any error messages but I know the `RegistrationView` register method isn't getting called.

Here's my `UserCreationForm`

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email",)

    def __int__(self):
        self.fields['password1'].required = False
        self.fields['password2'].required = False

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        clean_email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        user.email = clean_email
        if commit:
            user.save()
        custom_user = CustomUser()
        custom_user.id = user
        custom_user.save()
        return user
```

Here's my `RegistrationView`

```
class UserRegistration(RegistrationView):
    def __init__(self):
        self.form_class = UserCreateForm
        self.success_url = 'login'
        self.template_name = 'register.html'

    def register(self, request, form):
        new_user = form.save()
```

I'm using Django 1.8. Please let me know if any other information would be useful to share.

Comment: Where does this `RegistrationView` class come from? If it's a `FormView` then override `form_invalid`, add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`, and debug `form.errors`. I'm guessing it's a validation thing.

Comment: Also, your form class is overriding `__int__`, not `__init__`. That may be your problem.

Answer (score 17):

Programmatically, you *can* `create`/`save` a new `User` without a password argument, and it will *not* raise any exceptions. In fact, you can even `create` a user without any arguments. This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44101245).

The trick is to use `create()` instead of [create_user()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user), as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11545206).

For example, you can do this in your code:

```
User.objects.create(username='user without password')
```

The database field `password` will then contain an empty string. Because the user now exists, the admin will show the `UserChangeForm`, and the password will show up as a [ReadOnlyPasswordHashField](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L53) which says "**No password set.**", as you can see in the image below. You can proceed normally from there.

[image: screenshot of admin site]

Note that this empty password is *not* the same as an [unusable password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_usable_password). The `PasswordResetView` [does not work with an unusable password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView), but it *does* work with an empty password.

Also note that `User.objects.create(password='')` works, but `User.objects.create(password=None)` does not: the latter raises a `IntegrityError` due to the `NOT NULL` constraint in the database.

Just to illustrate the options, here's a test with different ways to create a user:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
import django.db
import django.db.transaction

RAW_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'


class UserTests(TestCase):
    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        # print passwords as stored in test database
        for user in User.objects.all():
            print(f'username: {user.username}\tpassword: {user.password}')

    def test_user_create_missing_required_fields(self):
        # none of these raise any exceptions, despite required model fields
        user_kwargs = [dict(),
                       dict(username='a'),
                       dict(username='b', password=''),
                       dict(username='c', password=RAW_PASSWORD)]
        for kwargs in user_kwargs:
            user = User.objects.create(**kwargs)
            # password is "usable" ...
            self.assertTrue(user.has_usable_password())
            if 'password' in kwargs:
                # stored password is still raw (not hashed)
                self.assertEqual(kwargs['password'], user.password)
                # ... but password-check fails
                self.assertFalse(user.check_password(kwargs['password']))

    def test_user_set_password(self):
        # can set a usable password after user creation
        user = User(username='d')
        user.set_password(RAW_PASSWORD)  # does not save...
        user.save()
        self.assertTrue(user.has_usable_password())
        self.assertNotEqual(RAW_PASSWORD, user.password)
        self.assertTrue(user.check_password(RAW_PASSWORD))

    def test_user_create_hashed_password(self):
        # we can initialize with a hashed password
        hashed_password = make_password(RAW_PASSWORD)
        user = User.objects.create(username='e', password=hashed_password)
        self.assertTrue(user.has_usable_password())
        self.assertTrue(user.check_password(RAW_PASSWORD))

    def test_user_set_unusable_password(self):
        # can set an unusable password
        user = User(username='f')
        user.set_unusable_password()  # does not save...
        user.save()
        self.assertFalse(user.has_usable_password())

    @django.db.transaction.atomic
    def test_user_create_password_none(self):
        # cannot initialize with password=None (violates the NOT NULL constraint)
        with self.assertRaises(django.db.IntegrityError) as a:
            User.objects.create(username='g', password=None)
        self.assertIn('not null', str(a.exception).lower())

    def test_user_set_password_none(self):
        # can set None in set_password(), but that becomes unusable
        user = User(username='h')
        user.set_password(None)
        user.save()
        self.assertFalse(user.has_usable_password())

    def test_user_force_login(self):
        # for testing, we can use force_login(),
        # even if the user is created without arguments
        user_without_args = User.objects.create()
        self.client.force_login(user=user_without_args)
        self.assertTrue(user_without_args.is_authenticated)
```

Comment: still today, this is not very well documented. that `user.password = ''` doesn't allow a user to login, but still allows him/her to reset the password and set it, is key, no?

Answer (score 14):

As you described, you modified the form fields to not require password, but what about the model? The build-in `User` model enforces use of password (it is required model field), and will give errors if you try to save a `User` objects without one. There's a special method for when you don't want to set a real password - [`django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password). Use it in your view before saving the form data.

Comment: The link you mentioned in your answer doesn't work. Can you please specify how to actually use that method?

Comment: @ZackPlauché Updated the link to point to the newest documentation. There's nothing to add - it's just a method on the User model, that one can call.