# Required field in Django model not mandatory?

Tags: django, model, required-field

I have the following Django model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

In my testcase, I instantiate it without an e-mail.

```
class CustomerTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_that_customer_can_be_created_with_minimum_data(self):
        customer = Customer.objects.create()
        print(customer.__dict__)
```

I expect it to raise an error, but it creates a record with an empty field `email`. The same thing happens if I explicitly say `null=False` and `blank=False`. Instead, it just prints the empty email.

```
{'email': ''}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: my models look like `class Customer(models.Model):`

Comment: Ah, yes, mine too. Forgot to add that here. Question remains the same. Updated the question now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the fact that validation is not run on save - see [the validation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run):

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form.

As that doc implies, usually validation is carried out in the context of a form.

Comment: [See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) for more info on validating models. To validate the entirety of the model use `.full_clean()`.

Comment: Mmm, that is clear! I thought that this would be set on the database level, but that is then an incorrect assumption. Thanks!