# How to test admin change views?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I got a rather complex admin change view for my Django model.

There is a lot of resources about how to test the admin list views (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498488/testing-admin-modeladmin-in-django)), but not for the change view.

How can I create a test cases for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test the admin change view of any model with Django's [test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client).

For that you will need the specific view URL for your model, which can be generated as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls).

Here is an example how to run a simple "loads normally" test for the Group model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse


def get_admin_change_view_url(obj: object) -> str:
    return reverse(
        'admin:{}_{}_change'.format(
            obj._meta.app_label,
            type(obj).__name__.lower()
        ),
        args=(obj.pk,)
    )


class TestGroupAdmin(TestCase):

    def test_change_view_loads_normally(self):
        # prepare client
        User.objects.create_superuser(
            username='superuser', password='secret', email='admin@example.com'
        )
        c = Client()
        c.login(username='superuser', password='secret')                

        # create test data
        my_group = Group.objects.create(name='Test Group')

        # run test
        response = c.get(get_admin_change_view_url(my_group))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that's more flexible to other models based off of Erik's answer.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse


def get_admin_change_view_url(obj: object) -> str:
    return reverse(
        'admin:{}_{}_change'.format(
            obj._meta.app_label,
            type(obj).__name__.lower()
        ),
        args=(obj.pk,)
    )


class BaseAdminTestCaseMixin:
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        user = User.objects.create_superuser(
            username='superuser', password='secret', email='admin@example.com'
        )
        self.c.force_login(user)

    def get_instance(self):
        raises NotImplementedError()
        instance, _ = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Test Group')
        return instance

    def test_change_view_loads_normally(self):
        instance = self.get_instance()
        response = self.client.get(get_admin_change_view_url(instance))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)


class TestGroupAdmin(BaseAdminTestCaseMixin, TestCase):
    def get_instance(self):
        instance, _ = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Test Group')
        return instance
```